# Microsoft Graph - 401, Unknown Error for /beta/education/classes/

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-edu

I am trying to make a request to the Microsoft Graph beta education endpoint to get a [list of assignments for a class](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/educationclass_list_assignments).

The request being made is:

```
/beta/education/classes/{class-id}/assignments
```

I set up the permission in Azure AD for reading assignments and the roster, and granted them.

I get an access token using client credentials using ADAL.NET, and the token seems to have the correct application permissions to read assignments:

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/5cf890b2-6a94-452f-8c29-9f7365b68ba0/",
  "iat": 1520000639,
  "nbf": 1520000639,
  "exp": 1520004539,
  "aio": "...",
  "app_displayname": "...",
  "appid": "...",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "e_exp": 262800,
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/5cf890b2-6a94-452f-8c29-9f7365b68ba0/",
  "oid": "bd0154f3-2626-40c1-82a5-39bc8879729c",
  "roles": [
    "EduRoster.Read.All",
    "EduAdministration.Read.All",
    "EduRoster.ReadBasic.All",
    "EduAssignments.Read.All"
  ],
  "sub": "...",
  "tid": "...",
  "uti": "...",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

However, looking in Fiddler, when I make a request with the token, it returns `401 unauthorized` with the following body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "bf6cd2e1-53a6-472a-b038-2b035eb8f7db",
      "date": "2018-03-02T14:41:41"
    }
  }
}
```

It seems to only be that endpoint that I can't access, as `/v1.0/education/users/{user-id}/classes` works correctly and returns the right response.

**Edit**

It seems that endpoint doesn't allow Application permissions for some reason, despite the permissions seemingly being applicable. I assume that ability is coming in the future.

I have tried moving back to using delegated permissions. This time, the scp's look as follows:

```
"scp": "AllSites.Read Calendars.Read Contacts.Read Directory.Read.All EduAdministration.Read EduAssignments.ReadWrite EduRoster.Read EduRoster.ReadBasic email Files.Read full_access_as_user Group.Read.All Mail.Read MyFiles.Read Notes.Read Notes.Read.All Notes.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp profile Sites.Read.All Sites.Search.All Tasks.Read TermStore.Read.All User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All"
```

The EduAssignments permissions are granted. The request now returns 403:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "Access denied.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "02f6d0d4-8867-4e43-94a4-d29f3a1e03f7",
      "date": "2018-03-02T20:47:06"
    }
  }
}
```

According to the docs, this seems to be by design. The permissions only allow users to access assignments from classes they are a member of. If I add myself to a class, then I can view its assignments.

However, what I want is the ability to view the assignments of any class, not just ones I am a member of. From the [permissions reference](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/concepts/permissions_reference.md#education-permissions), there are application permissions designed to do what I want:

> **EduAssignments.Read.All**: Read class assignments with grades. Allows the app to read assignments and their grades for all users.

However, that endpoint simply doesn't support them.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation, you can't call that endpoint with app permissions. It needs to be a delegated call under a user identity.

> Application   Not supported.

The reason you can call `/v1.0/education/users/{user-id}/classes` is because it allows Application-only calls with roles:

> EduRoster.Read.All, EduRoster.ReadWrite.All

And you have one of those, so that succeeds.

Comment: Missed that bit in the documentation. I've updated my question